# iterate over days and pull in price information

Tags: r

This is a follow on question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54336092/rgdax-coinbase-data-not-collecting-data-as-expected/54337426?noredirect=1#comment95508937_54337426). Thanks to @nate for the helpful solution.

I am trying to collect price data from coinbase. What I have so far is the following:

```
start <- strftime(Sys.time() - 86400, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", tz = "UTC")
end <- strftime(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", tz = "UTC") 
product_id = "ETH-EUR"
granularity = 300
# request url
req.url <- paste0("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/", product_id, "/candles")
req.url
# fetching the data ourselves - the return
res <- httr::GET(url = req.url, 
                 query = list(start = start, end = end, 
                              granularity = granularity))
res <- as.data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(httr::content(res)), nrow = 6)))
res[['V1']] <- as.POSIXct(.subset2(res,1L), origin="1970-01-01")
c(min(res$V1),max(res$V1)) 

colnames(res) <- c("time", "low", "high", "open", "close", "volume")
```

Which gives the following:

```
> c(min(res$V1),max(res$V1))
[1] "2019-01-23 13:45:00 CET" "2019-01-24 13:40:00 CET"
```

(The last 24 hours worth of data)

If I change the `start` and `end` times to the following:

```
start <- strftime(Sys.time() - 86400*5, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", tz = "UTC")
end <- strftime(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", tz = "UTC")
```

(Collect the last 5 days worth of data) - coinbase does not allow so much data to be collected.

However it is possible to collect:

```
 t = 5 and t = 4
 t= 4 and t = 3
 t = 3 and t = 2
 t = 2 and t = 1
 t = 1 and t = 0
```

So collect data 5 days ago and subtract 24 hours from that date.
 Something like the following:

```
start <- strftime(Sys.time() - 86400*5, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", tz = "UTC")
end <- strftime(Sys.time() - 86400*(5-1), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", tz = "UTC")
```

Which Works. So knowing this I am trying to créate a function which Will "loop" of iterate over the dates and pull in the information.

I have been working on the following - but I know a function would be 100 times better than what I currentlu have:

```
start <- NULL
end <- NULL
for(i in 1:5){
  start[[i]] <- as.data.frame(strftime(Sys.time() - 86400*i, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", tz = "UTC"))
  end[[i]] <- as.data.frame(strftime(Sys.time() - 86400*(i-1), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", tz = "UTC"))
}

start <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, start)
end <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, end)

colnames(start) <- "start"
colnames(end) <- "end"


for(i in 1:5){
  res[[i]] <- httr::GET(url = req.url, 
                   query = list(start = start[i, ], end = end[i, ], 
                                granularity = 300))
}
```

Do you have any tips on how to apply this to a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function like this

```
# Function
coinbaseGET <- function (product_id, start, end, granularity) {
  # request url
  req.url <- paste0("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/", product_id, "/candles")
  req.url
  # fetching the data ourselves - the return
  res <- httr::GET(url = req.url, 
                   query = list(start = start, end = end, 
                                granularity = granularity))
  res <- as.data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(httr::content(res)), nrow = 6)))
  res[['V1']] <- as.POSIXct(.subset2(res,1L), origin="1970-01-01")
  res
}
```

And the looping through the dates using for instance `lapply`

```
# Variables
product_id = "ETH-EUR"
granularity = 300
start_dates <- Sys.time() -  86400*(1:10)         # considering the last 10 days
end_dates <- Sys.time() -  86400*(0:9)

# Looping
res <- lapply(seq_along(end_dates), 
              function (k) coinbaseGET(product_id, start_dates[k], end_dates[k], granularity))
res <- do.call(rbind, res)
```

With the result

```
str(res)
# 'data.frame': 2813 obs. of  6 variables:
#   $ V1: POSIXct, format: "2019-01-24 13:55:00" "2019-01-24 13:50:00" "2019-01-24 13:45:00" "2019-01-24 13:40:00" ...
# $ V2: num  103 102 102 103 102 ...
# $ V3: num  103 103 103 103 103 ...
# $ V4: num  103 102 103 103 102 ...
# $ V5: num  103 103 102 103 103 ...
# $ V6: num  9.63 18.11 30.07 80.98 12.75 ...

# Checking the dates
c(min(res$V1), max(res$V1))
# [1] "2019-01-14 15:00:00 CET" "2019-01-24 13:55:00 CET"]
```

Comment: Thanks again! the `lapply` Works great. One question about the `function`. I use the following `df <- coinbaseGET(product_id, start, end, granularity)` but only get the last 24 hours. Is this function supposed to collect multiple dates?

Comment: @user8959427 I believe it depends on the `granularity`: I tried with `start = t - 5; end =  t` and I receive the notification from Coinbase *granularity too small for the requested time range*. So I guess with `granularity = 300`, the function is suited for daily data, i.e. `start = t - 1`. You will find more information here https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/

Comment: @user8959427 Also, keep in mind there are *rate limits*.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Did you reach any limit? I do not expect to be doing anything high frequency - maybe pulling the data 4 time an hour or a couple times a day.

Comment: @user8959427 Yeah I pulled the data for the last ten days for a couple of cryptos and got the message *slow rate limit exceeded* - I think I sent too many requests in a given minute or so.

Comment: I am getting `Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format` - when I change the dates to a much larger time scale `systemtime <- Sys.time()  start_dates <- systemtime -  86400*(1:100)  
end_dates <- systemtime -  86400*(0:99)`. Perhaps a sleep or pause function could be added.